# Inkscape adding seemingly random amount of pixels to vertical coordinates

Tags: xml, svg, graphics, vector-graphics, inkscape

I've been using an SVG as an inline SVG. However, for whatever reason, out of the blue and all of a sudden Inkscape randomly started adding 57.5 pixels to vertical coordinates. Below is a screenshot. At first I thought it was my code, though now it's apparent that's not the case. Apparently each layer has a different coordinate system, even though they share the same viewbox and what not.

[image]

Since the line is placed in the corner of the document one would expect the coordinates to be:

```
    M 2, 2 H 13
```

and not

```
    M 2, 58.5 H 13
```

but obviously this is not the case. Below is what it ends up looking like in the browser.

[image]

I've never experienced anything like this before, so I would be incredibly grateful if somebody knows and can explain what's causing this unusual behaviour.

FWIW, I'm using version 0.92.

Comment: [Could this be what happened?](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=12352)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Hey, Paul. Got it sorted overnight. A couple people responded on my [Inkscape thread]http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=32050&p=97304#p97304. Apparently layers are treated as groups, and all of the elements in a layer, as if it were a group of elements, can have transforms applied to them or the layer itself. A quick solution is simply to create a new layer, and just copy the stuff to another layer.